# График частоты вхождения элемента в список

Tags: python, matplotlib

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли сделать график частоты вхождения элементов в список?

```
list_1 = [(1, 4), (1,), (1, 0), (1, 0), (3, 1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 0), (3, 2, 0), (2, 0), (2, 0), (10,), (3, 2, 0), (2, 0)]
c2 = Counter(list_1)
print(c2)
```

Вывод:

```
Counter({(1, 0): 4, (2, 0): 3, (3, 2, 0): 2, (1, 4): 1, (1,): 1, (3, 1, 0): 1, (10,): 1})
```

Comment: Да, можно, конечно.

Comment: @strawdog, подскажите как пожалуйста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно, например, так:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter

list_1 = [(1, 4), (1,), (1, 0), (1, 0), (3, 1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 0), (3, 2, 0), (2, 0), (2, 0), (10,), (3, 2, 0), (2, 0)]
c2 = Counter(list_1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = list(range(len(c2)))

patches = ax.bar(data = c2, x = x, height=c2.values())
ax.bar_label(patches)
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(c2.keys())
plt.show()
```

получите
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант - через `Seaborn`, у него и метод свой есть для подсчёта. Но кортежи он что-то не хочет брать, пришлось в строки превратить:

```py
import seaborn as sns

list_1 = [(1, 4), (1,), (1, 0), (1, 0), (3, 1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 0), (3, 2, 0), (2, 0), (2, 0), (10,), (3, 2, 0), (2, 0)]

sns.countplot(y=list(map(str,list_1)))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]